# Can not load ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

When I start the computer it seems ubuntu is loading normally, but a few seconds later I get black screen with this message:

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0 - 1ubuntu1) built-in shel (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands

(initramfs)_

From there I can only 'reboot'. I typed 'help' and i got a list of commands i dont know and tried some of them like exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recovery Mode - Terminal**

Have you tried rebooting into recovery mode? When the boot options screen appears:

Advanced options > ***** (recovery mode)
[Accessing recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153131/how-do-you-recover-from-a-failed-upgrade-apt-get-f-install-and-dpkg-confi)

This will allow you to access the terminal as root, and update graphics drivers etc.

**Fixes**

Back up first! you may damage your system trying to fix it so use this guide to backup in recovery mode.

[Copy files to USB in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272267/how-do-i-to-copy-files-to-flash-drive-in-a-recovery-mode)

It depends on what your problem is specifically. But here's some similar problems that may apply to you.

- [Stuck at busybox](https://askubuntu.com/a/137912/322860)
- [Failed Ubuntu Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153131/how-do-you-recover-from-a-failed-upgrade-apt-get-f-install-and-dpkg-confi)

Comment: I did it using a live cd instead of recovery mode and it worked - ty